# $C^k$ hypersurfaces can be split in this way?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds

Let $S$ be a bounded $C^k$ hypersurface of dimension $n \geq 2$ in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ **with no boundary**.

Is it true that $S$ can be split into two hypersurfaces $S_1, S_2$ that have boundary, and a compact hypersurface $\Gamma$? Is $\Gamma$ connected?

This is true when $S$ is a sphere for example. The equater is $\Gamma$ and the $S_i$ are the hemisphere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, in a rather boring way. Take a point $p\in S$. In a neighborhood of $p$, the surface can be represented (in a suitable coordinate system) by equation $x_{n+1}=g(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ for some smooth function $g$. For a small $r>0$, let $$ S_1=\{x: x_{n+1}=g(x_1,\dots,x_n), \ x_1^2+\dots+x_n^2<r^2\} $$  $$ \Gamma=\{x: x_{n+1}=g(x_1,\dots,x_n), \ x_1^2+\dots+x_n^2=r^2\} $$ 
and $S_2=S\setminus (S_1\cup \Gamma)$. The separating hypersurface $\Gamma$ is connected.